# What would be the effect on capacitance when a dielectric is placed on top of parallel plate capacitor?

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

Assume there is a parallel plate capacitor connected to 5V DC source.
The dielectric present in between the plates is air. 
Now we place a dielectric on top of plate connected to positive terminal of the DC source. (assume relative permittivity of dielectric to be 5). What will be the effect of such a configuration on the capacitance of the parallel plate?
An image for the configuration is provided below:

[image]

Comment: @sammygerbil I meant dielectric is placed outside of the plates. I have provided the diagram above.

Answer (score 1):

For an ideal capacitor, there is no electric field outside of the gap between them. If there is no field, there is no polarization of the medium - so "the capacitor doesn't know it's there", and there is no effect on the capacitance.

Comment: what about non-ideal scenarios, where the charges are distributed over the entire surface of the plate?

Comment: Charges will be "almost entirely" on the inside surface. The only non-ideality is that a little bit of the electric field "leaks out" of the sides of the capacitor. In principle, adding the dielectric _may_ increase the capacitance **by a tiny amount**. And I do mean tiny.

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12309/26969

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the charges to be concentrated on the inside of the surface?

Comment: Of course - the opposite charges attract!